# If $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$, then $\cos(\theta/2) < 0$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is this statement true or false and why?

> If $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, then $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) < 0$?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What does $\cos\times{\theta\over2}$ means?

Comment: Have you figured out the possible values for $\theta/2$?  Do you know when $\cos x < 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that for

$$\frac \pi 2<  \theta <\pi \implies \frac \pi 4<  \frac \theta 2 <\frac \pi 2 \implies 0<\cos \theta<\frac {\sqrt 2} 2$$

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this. $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$ means that we are working in the second quadrant, so we can set $\theta$ = $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and plug $\theta$ into the statement given which is $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$. If we do that, we get $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$, which is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, and $\frac{1}{2} > 0$. Therefore, the statement, if $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, then $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) < 0$, is false.